# OSX script for triggering Google Chrome's Voice Search keyboard shortcut

Tags: google-chrome, applescript, google-search

In the Google Chrome browser (on a mac), you can activate the Google Voice Search by pressing Command+Shift+Period from htttp://google.com.

Assuming the url http://google.com is loaded in a chrome tab with the search box in focus, shouldn't the following applescript work?

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    activate
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke "." using {command down, shift down}
end tell
```

For some reason it won't work, and I don't understand why because the following script will fill the search field with text as expected:

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    activate
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke "this test works as expected"
end tell
```

How can I trigger the google voice search with a script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
tell application "Google Chrome" to activate
tell application "System Events"
    key code 47 using {command down, shift down}
end tell
delay 3
```